# Saving Mobile Number in iOS Application

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am working with an iOS application in which i have to save the Mobile number from which number i am getting the call on my device. After Completion of the call i want to save the number in my own iOS application.
Please guide me . Is it possible to save Mobile number after completion of call.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is **NOT** possible, apps aren't allowed to read or write data outside their designated container.

It will be rejected from the Apple App Store Review Process for

> **2.6** Apps that read or write data outside its designated container area will be rejected

**EDIT**

As for your comments

> "sir can i access call history log and from there i can store Mobile number."

**NO** you can't access the call history for exactly the same reason because you are reading outside of the designated container so again would be rejected under **2.6**

**EDIT 2**

Another reason that your app would get rejected if you try accessing call history will be because it is accessing private files and APIs because the call history database is located `/private/var/root/Library/CallHistory/call_history.db` which if you notice has **private** in it so not available to us in simple terms, so would possibly get rejected for **2.5** as well but I would probably go with they would rejected your app mainly for **2.6**

> **2.5** Apps that use non-public APIs will be rejected

Comment: sir can i access call history log and from there i can store Mobile number.

Comment: You might be able to do it but it doesn't mean it should be done or even allowed to be done.

Comment: @Rausi There is no way to access call history. This is sensitive data which is contained within phone.app. You cannot access data outside the sandbox of your own application.

Comment: @popeye :  sir can you please tell me the way by which i can retreive the data from call history log.

Comment: @Rausi How do I know I don't work for Apple, who knows the reasons behind what Apple do. The only thing you need to know is it is not allowed.